# Android Eclipse not hitting breakpoints / not printing to Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm not really sure what else I can do with this. Here's a function that refuses to print the stacktrace whatever I do. I'm not sure if it's because Eclipse isnt' deploying the right .apk to the emulator or if it's something I'm doing. So:

```
private String getStringFromResponse(HttpResponse response) {
    try {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        String responseXMLString = str.toString();
        return responseXMLString;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        String stackTrace = ex.getStackTrace().toString();
        Log.i("PPKMCC-NtwrkAccessClass", stackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is an exception at `str.toString()`. I don't know the cause because I'm not able to view the stacktrace. I don't think it's because of the size of the response because the same code was downloading the prefs fine till now.

In the `catch` block, `printStackTrace()` doesn't output to the Logcat. I have a break point at `String stacktrace` but it doesn't hit that particular breakpoint and instead goes directly to `return null`. I've tried resetting the emulator, creating a completely new emulator instance, cleaning my project, none of them seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: so if you put a breakpoint at the InputStream in= line it never stops there (and you are using debug mode, not just running the app?).  Also, how do you know thats where the exception is if you don't get the stack trace?

Comment: It breaks fine at `String responseXMLString = str.toString();`. I try to step over to the next step and it jumps directly to `return null`. No stacktrace gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the StackTrace,

you can't directly print the Stacktrace like in Java, you have to do a bit of gymnastic.
you can try this:

```
Log.e("jason", "Login exception triggered : "+ e.getMessage() +"\n"+e);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream( baos );
e.printStackTrace(stream);
stream.flush();
Log.e("jason", new String( baos.toByteArray() ) );
```

Regarding the breakpoint:

I would suggest:

1) check that the function is called

2) check that you are launching in debug

3) check that your manifest allows debug

Regarding the str.toString(), I think it can only crash when called on a null object.
I would suggest adding a

```
`if(str != null)
{
   //toString
}else{
   Log.e(TAG,"str == null");
}
```

`

Hope it helps

Jason

Comment: Yes, the function works fine till the stmt `String responseXMLString = str.toString();`. It hits the breakpoint there and I try to step over to the next step (F6) and it jumps directly to `return null` even when I have breakpoints at `ex.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: add the code to print the stack that I posted. your current code won't print the stack. why it doesn't stop that I can only guess. I remember once I had to rest the phone to factory settings to get it to update my code lol

Comment: Oh, I've set `debuggable="false"` in my manifest to create a release version of my application and completely forgot about it. I've removed it now and it works. Why does it even hit breakpoints if debuggable is set to false?